# Tags for [invocation], [start-up] and [command-line-arguments]

Tags: discussion, tags

I was looking for a tag for a question about getting Emacs to do something at startup based on the command line arguments. I didn't find any so I created [command-line-arguments](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-line-arguments). As I was looking for other applicable questions, I finally found [invocation](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/invocation) and [start-up](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/start-up).

Is [invocation](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/invocation) close enough to [command-line-arguments](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-line-arguments) to be a synonym? [Invocation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Emacs-Invocation.html#Emacs-Invocation) is mostly about command line arguments; other things can be relevant ([environment variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/General-Variables.html#General-Variables), [X resources](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Resources.html#Resources), [Windows integration](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Windows-Startup.html#Windows-Startup)) but they are grouped separately in the documentation. [command-line-arguments](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-line-arguments) can apply to looking up command line arguments after start-up too.

What about [start-up](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/start-up)? I think it covers [a lot more ground](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Starting-Up.html#Starting-Up), with [command line arguments](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Command_002dLine-Arguments.html#Command_002dLine-Arguments) just one aspect.

Comment: `invocation` does not imply invocation of Emacs.  More often it refers to the invocation of a function. `start-up` is almost as problematic - it could refer to the startup of a process. `command-line-arguments` is pretty unambiguous, IMO, but of course it is about the startup arguments and not just about startup of Emacs.